# How do I transform an XML element name into an attribute value using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given the XML snippet:

```
<transactions>
  <tran id="1">
    <E8>
      <datestamp>2012-05-17T15:16:57Z</datestamp>
    </E8>
  </tran>
</transactions>
```

How do I transform the element `<E8>` into `<event type="E8">` using XSLT?

Edit: Expected output:

```
<transactions>
  <tran id="1">
    <event type="E8">
      <datestamp>2012-05-17T15:16:57Z</datestamp>
    </event>
  </tran>
</transactions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tran/*">
    <event type="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    </event>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<transactions>
  <tran id="1">
    <event type="E8">2012-05-17T15:16:57Z</event>
  </tran>
</transactions>
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question, but it's not quite the output I was expecting (see edit). I still need to keep all child elements of the E8 element (there can be more than one). Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: I figured it out. Used `<xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

Comment: @JordanDedels, actually, using `xsl:copy-of` isn't the best solution -- if in the future you'd need to transform these children, then you'll have to remove this instruction.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, That's a good point. I'm new to XLST, so thanks for the heads up. I'll use the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` as shown in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tran/E8">
  <event type="E8">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </event>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<transactions>
  <tran id="1">
    <E8>
      <datestamp>2012-05-17T15:16:57Z</datestamp>
    </E8>
  </tran>
</transactions>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<transactions>
   <tran id="1">
      <event type="E8">
         <datestamp>2012-05-17T15:16:57Z</datestamp>
      </event>
   </tran>
</transactions>
```